# Redo Undo for wpf user control at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

i have wpf application, in my application on one editor user can add n number of user control and for each user control he can edit or enter properties, i want to add redo undo functionality for this editor,i.e. for add user control remove user control, move user control edit user control properties at run-time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Unfortunately, this is a VERY broad question.  What have you tried so far?  Usually undo/redo functionality is implemented by tracking the state of the document at all times, and moving back (or forward) a step when needed.  This is not something that can easily be answered fully, especially given the minimum effort involved in the question!

Answer (score -2):

Run the program and type some text into the TextBox before clicking the two buttons. To see the way that multiple changes can be undone, type some text, click Undo and then Redo, then add extra text. It will now be possible to undo twice.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but this doesn't answer the (very broad, as it is) question in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @Morampudi what program are you talking about? I have a hard time seeing any code provided by op..